# Fortran 77 function return type mismatch

Tags: function, fortran, gfortran, type-mismatch

I've been trying to learn Fortran 77 for a university project and I write the following code in windows 10 :

```
program Q_Value
real BEs(4),Masses(4)
real Q,Tthr
integer i,Nuclei(4,2),A,Z

do 10 i=1,4,1
        write(*,100)'Give the info for Nuclei:',i
 100        format(A,I1)
        write(*,*)'A='
        read(*,*)Nuclei(i,1)
        write(*,*)'Z='
        read(*,*)Nuclei(i,2)
        if((Nuclei(i,1).EQ.0).OR.(Nuclei(i,2).EQ.0))then
            BEs(i)=0.
        else
            BEs(i)=BetheWeiss(Nuclei(i,1),Nuclei(i,2))
        endif
        Masses(i)=Mass(Nuclei(i,1),Nuclei(i,2),BEs(i))
 10 continue

[...]
end
real function Mass(A,Z,BE)
    integer A,Z
    real BE,mass
c   local var's
    parameter(Mp=938.2720813,Mn=939.5654133)
c   statements
    Mass=((A-Z)*Mn)+(Z*Mp)-BE
    return 
    end
```

When compiling in GNU Fortran (gfortran 8.1.0) I get the following error:

```
Masses(i)=Mass(Nuclei(i,1),Nuclei(i,2),BEs(i))
                     1
Error: Return type mismatch of function 'mass' at (1) (INTEGER(4)/REAL(4))
```

Can anyone help me out with this because as far as I am concerned my function return a real number and `Masses(i)` is a real variable.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps the compiler is dealing with some type resolution with the integer elements of the equation within the function, eg 'integer A,Z' and their involvement in the Mass calculation just before the return statement. Perhaps gnu fortran has more stringent type rules?

Comment: Thanks for your reply  @David W .I tried to convert A and Z with dble in the last formula(Mass=....) but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Well, I must admit my fortran is pretty stale, but what if you took the typedef off the function and ensured the declaration for the return type matched  - and both were specified with the same case

Comment: Didn't you want to write `implicit integer (A-Z)` instead of `integer A,Z`? But even if yes, what you actually want is `implicit none` in ALL of your program units (the main program, your functions, your subroutines). Also, strongly consider some version of Fortran from this century. Please check that you copied your source code exactly. Please make it a [mcve] that we can compile ourselves without any `[...]`.

Comment: @Theodepastas I finally figured out the solution. Posted an answer; tried it out on an online compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implicit typing rule is that if the first letter of the name is I , J , K , L , M , or N , then the data type is integer, otherwise it is real.

Because your function is `mass()`, it starts with M and is not declared within the main program, it is considered to be an integer function there. That conflicts with the function declaration and the compiler complains. What you need, if you want to keep the extremely ancient FORTRAN 77 is

```
real mass
```

in the main program.

It is much better to use the features of modern Fortran, starting with `IMPLICIT NONE` and putting the function into a module or making it internal to the main program.

You could also fix the error message using an alternative implicit statement in the main program (see my comment) but I **strongly** discourage anything else than `IMPLICIT NONE`.

Answer (score 0):

The function Mass is declared outside the scope of the main program. As a result, the compiler infers a type for the Mass function even though it is expressly declared in the same source block. To overcome this, you need to declare an interface block in the calling program:

```
program Q_Value
[...]
interface Mass
  real function Mass(A,Z,BE)
  integer :: A
  integer :: Z 
  real :: BE
  end function
  end interface 

end program

real function Mass(A, Z, BE)
[..]
end function
```

I have a working, modified version of your original source with this solution at https://onlinegdb.com/BkjLxcy9S. I removed the call to BetheWeiss and replaced it with an arbitrary assignment, inferring it was merely a function you defined in the omitted source from your original post. You'll need the same kind of interface there as well.

Comment: Note that it is not Fortran 77 compatible, but it is one of the Fortran 90 techniques to solve this problem. This technique is fine for interfacing old-style functions as a one-off, but modules are much better to learn in general. Certainly interfaces are not a general tool to write larger programs in modern Fortran. In this specific case it is also faster just to use `contains` before the function and `end program` after the function (as I say in the answer - make the function internal). Again, modules are much better in general. Do not underestimate the importance of `implicit none`.

Comment: No suggestion this was a broad or universal solution; merely a means to achieve the objective of solving the compilation problem. I'm sure there are many other issues that will arise with any project involving use of a language of this vintage.